# Flutter: installing dependencies on code magic failing

Tags: android, flutter, automated-tests

I'm trying to create automatic tests for my flutter project and I'm using codemagic for this. https://codemagic.io Anyways, everything works fine on my local machine; however, when I try to run it on codemagic it fails on installing dependencies. Here's part of the output for where it's failing:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script '/Users/builder/programs/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle' line: 200

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':path_provider'.
> Failed to notify project evaluation listener.
   > Could not get unknown property 'android' for project ':path_provider' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
   > Could not find method debugProvided() for arguments [file collection] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

I've done some searching related to these errors. I'm seeing a few possible solutions such as upgrading gradle version and make a few adjustments in my files. However, none of the problems pertain to my problem (codemagic) and the solutions generally aren't working. The solutions I was following was they were running on their local machine and they get the error. Mine works locally, but not on the cloud testing environment. Any ideas? (Let me know if there are certain files I should post) Thanks!

Comment: Some codemagic errors can be related to having a different Flutter version locally vs on Codemagic. Check if those two are the same. Also, it's worth to use a fixed Flutter version on Codemagic, to avoid broken pipelines in case of a new Flutter release.